# Invalid object name 'column_name'

Tags: sql-server

I have created a procedure as

```
create procedure testPagination
(
@PageNumber bigint,
@PageSize Bigint,
@OrderByColumn varchar(1000),
@OrderType varchar(1000)
)
As
Begin
    --print @PageNumber
    --print @PageSize

    declare @strSQL nvarchar(max)
    declare @intStartSrNo bigint
    declare @intEndSrNo bigint

    if @OrderType = 'asc' 
    begin
        set @intStartSrNo=((@PageNumber*@PageSize)-@PageSize)
        set @intEndSrNo=(@PageNumber*@PageSize)
    end
    else if @OrderType = 'desc' 
    begin
        create table #RecCount(cnt bigint)
        declare @intTotRecords bigint
        set @strSQL='insert into #RecCount(cnt) select isnull(max(a.sr_no),0) from ' + @OrderByColumn + ' a with(nolock)'
        exec sp_executesql @strSQL
        select @intTotRecords=cnt from #RecCount



        set @intStartSrNo=(@intTotRecords-(@PageNumber*@PageSize))+1
        set @intEndSrNo=((@intStartSrNo-1)+@PageSize)

    end
    else
    begin
        return
    end


    if @OrderType = 'asc' 
    begin
        set @strSQL=
        '
        select a.sr_no, bv.id,bv.name_voter,bv.home_street_address_1, bv.home_address_city from ' + @OrderByColumn + ' a with(nolock) ' +
        ' inner join base_voter bv with(nolock) on bv.id=a.base_voter_id where a.sr_no > ' + cast(@intStartSrNo as varchar(500)) + ' and a.sr_no <= ' + cast(@intEndSrNo as varchar(500))
    end
    else if @OrderType = 'desc' 
    begin
        set @strSQL=
        '
        select a.sr_no, bv.id,bv.name_voter,bv.home_street_address_1, bv.home_address_city from ' + @OrderByColumn + ' a with(nolock) ' +
        ' inner join base_voter bv with(nolock) on bv.id=a.base_voter_id where a.sr_no >= ' + cast(@intStartSrNo as varchar(500)) + ' and a.sr_no <= ' + cast(@intEndSrNo as varchar(500))
    end
    --print @strSQL
    exec sp_executesql @strSQL
    return

End
go
```

3 indexes as

```
 create index IX_base_voter_name_voter_asc_deleted_at on base_voter(name_voter asc,deleted_at) include(home_street_address_1, home_address_city) where deleted_at is null 
 create index IX_base_voter_home_street_address_1_asc_deleted_at on base_voter(home_street_address_1 asc,deleted_at) include(name_voter, home_address_city) where deleted_at is null 
 create index IX_base_voter_home_address_city_asc_deleted_at on base_voter(home_address_city asc,deleted_at) include(name_voter, home_street_address_1) where deleted_at is null
```

Now, when I try to execute this stored procedure I receive the error

**Invalid Object name 'home_address_city'**

I am executing by right-clicking on the stored procedure, which actually executes the following query

```
USE [test_db]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[testPagination]
        @PageNumber = 1,
        @PageSize = 50,
        @OrderByColumn = N'home_address_city',
        @OrderType = N'asc'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I have already hit `ctrl+shift+r` a lot but with no success

Comment: What happens when you `print @strSQL`? Show us that. Seems like you didn't copy the code correctly or were relying on a different string being passed into `@OrderByColumn`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I had made a comment here. Could you please reply to that comment on your answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479677/sql-server-count-is-slow/12480084#comment93820968_12480084

Comment: I updated my answer there but please don't do this - badgering people on a completely unrelated question - I get the same comment notification here that I get there, so all this did is tell me twice that you made a comment. Have patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proc contains this dynamic code:

```
set @strSQL='insert into #RecCount(cnt) select isnull(max(a.sr_no),0) from ' + @OrderByColumn + ' a with(nolock)'
```

When executed, this code throws the error mentioned above because from context it seems that `Some Column` is passed through `@OrderByColumn`, but your code tries to do a `SELECT` from this Some Column.

Comment: I don't get it. By the way, the same code is working for another table. I created a new database for some reason and tried to copy the stored procedure. But, it not working in for this table

Comment: What do you pass in with your parameter @OrderByColumn? Is it column name, or table name, or you have both the table and the column with the same name? Your code could execute without errors only if there is also a TABLE with the same name as the column that you pass in as a parameter

Comment: My bad I was missing a query which was creating a table with the same name as column name such as

    `create table home_address_city
    (
    sr_no bigint,
    base_voter_id int,
    constraint pk_home_address_city_sr_no primary key (sr_no)
    )`

Thanks, for pointing my fault.